# Finding range of a polynomial expression.

Tags: functions, quadratics

> Consider $ y=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ , where x is real , then find the range of the expression $y^2 + y - 2$.

I solved it by factorising the expression and then simplifying 
$$y^2 + y - 2$$
$$= (y+2)(y-1)$$
$$= (\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+2)(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}-1)$$
$$= -2(\frac{(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

I cannot solve further from here as I can't find range of this expression.

Comment: Do you know AM-GM or maybe just $(x - 1)^2 \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Azlif Yes,I know the inequalities but it can help in simplifying it?

Comment: If you know the inequality, you'll get $1 + x^2 \geq 2x$ which you can then use to obtain $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ and equality can hold.

Comment: @Azlif Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y^2+y-2=\dfrac{(2y+1)^2-9}4$$

WLOG $x=\tan A\implies y=\sin2A$

$2y+1=2\sin2A+1$

and $-2+1\le2\sin2A+1\le2+1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Find the range of $y$ first. Say it is $[\alpha,\beta\kern 1.5mu]$. Then find the image of the interval  $[\alpha,\beta\mkern 1.5mu]$ by the function $y^2+y-2$.

Comment: I am still confused.How is finding image of interval related to finding the range ?

Comment: The range of a function is the image of its domain. The range of a composition is the image by the second function of the image of the first function.  Isn't it clear?

Comment: @Thank you very much sir for your help.